# How to get rid of Gmail conversations and make them separate threads when google form submits?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that sends emails based of certain conditions. When the emails are sent, they combine as conversations. Is there a way to program google apps script to send emails as separate threads when the google form is submitted? A taste of my code is below? I'm assuming I'll have to generate some kind of ID for the email? Any help is appreciated.

```
function sendEmailToTech(tInfo) {
  // Recipient emails based on building choice
  var tEmail = "abc1234@gmail.com";

  // Compose the email
  var subject = 'Building Request From Approved';
  var body = "<b>Requester Information:</b>\n\n" + tInfo.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'); // Wrap the requester information in <b> tags and replace line breaks with <br> tags
  var recipientList = tEmail;

  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientList,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: body
  });
}
```

I tried generating a unique ID for each email being sent, but failed. Instead, it sent the email multiple times.

Comment: I don't  think so.  You can do it manually but I've never see the ability to do it via script.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. 

function sendEmailToT(tInfo) {
  var subject = 'Building Request From Approved - ' + Date.now().toString(); // Append a timestamp to the subject 

If you append a date/string to the subject line, it fixes the conversation issue.